# AND query nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

Full disclaimer: elasticsearch noob here.

I'm using the nested field `value_per_id` for an array of objects. Each object has the properties: `value` and `id`.
E.g.

```
"value_per_id": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": "positive"
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "value": "positive"
  },
  {
    "id": 65,
    "value": "neutral"
  }
]
```

I have a query that looks like this (edited for clarity):

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : {
              "nested" : {
                "path" : "value_per_id",
                "query" : [
                  {"terms" : {"value_per_id.value" : <MY_VALUES>}},
                  {"terms" : {"value_per_id.id" : <MY_IDS>}},
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With this query, I get all the elements that have an object with value in MY_VALUES OR id in MY_IDS.

I want all the elements that have value in MY_VALUES for any id in MY_IDS.

(E.g. if `MY_VAULES = ['positive', 'neutral']` and `MY_IDS = [1, 2]`, I want those that have an object with 1 - positive, 1 - negative, 2 - positive or 2 - negative).

What's the syntax for this?

EDIT - Wrong format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the bool within the nested query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "nested": {
                    "path": "value_per_id",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {"term": {"value_per_id.value": 1}},
                                {"term": {"value_per_id.id": 2}}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this way is how I ended up solving the problem. More info here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `must` or `filter` in the bool query.

If you use `must`, the sub queries will contribute to the score, if you use `filter` they won't. Also, if you use `filter` elasticsearch will be able to cache the results.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "value_per_id",
                    "query": {
                        "terms": {
                            "value_per_id.value": <MY_VALUES>
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "value_per_id",
                    "query": {
                        "terms": {
                            "value_per_id.id": <MY_IDS>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. I think I'm getting `OR` logic when I do that (that is, value in MY_VALUES OR id in MY_IDS). What I want is `AND` logic. Maybe it was not clear before, because format was removing part of my question.

Comment: Still this is not correct. If I have a result with the objects [{id: 1, value: negative},{id: 3, value: positive}], it will pass the filter (taking the id 1 from the first object, and the value positive for the second). I need that there is at least one object inside the result that passes both filters